# Multiple SSL IIS Web Site Publishing

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, ssl

https://site.com/Pages/Membership/Registration.aspx is using 443 ssl post on the other hand i want to use diffrent ssl certificate for  sub domain https://login.site.com/ but same port error

Answer (score 1):

I think that when binding SSL ports in IIS, each SSL binding has to be bound to a separate IP address. So you'd need an additional IP address for your server.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use SSL Host Headers and be running IIS 6 or later.

http://www.sslshopper.com/article-how-to-configure-ssl-host-headers-in-iis-6.html